# Getting ProcessBuilder (or command execution in general) working on Mac with JRE?

Tags: java, macos, command-line, command

I do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", updater.getAbsolutePath(), downStuff.getAbsolutePath(), actStuff.getAbsolutePath(), toRunAfter.getAbsolutePath());
pb.start();
```

...passing 3 string file paths as an arguments. Working beautifully on Windows, but Mac keeps saying: "No Java runtime present, requesting install."

Do I need to install JDK to client's machine just to get this simple command working? ...or is there any other way how I can run external jar file programatically while passing an arguments?

Because right now it seems like I'll have to save those three lines of text into a file just because Oracle and Apple didn't solve their s**t together...

Comment: I don't know why the `java` executable isn't in your execution path, but I know that application updates should be delivered using Web Start.  All you would need to do is place the updated version on a server;  no need to explicitly run any external programs, ever.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use webstart without a web browser? Jnlp support seems to be more and more rare thing. Also I need user to choose if he wants to update or not.

Comment: Yes, although for some reason the documentation hasn't been included with Java since 1.5: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/cdinstall.03.06.html

Comment: Just based on your suggestion, I managed to put the app on web and download jnlp, run it out of it. ...but it seems like it downloads the appliaction and then runs it out of local cache. When I do some change in the application, upload it, and run it even from that newly generated jnlp, the old version launches. Is there way to force jnlp to attempt downloading new version before every run?

Comment: You could put `<update check="always" policy="prompt-update"/>` in your JNLP file, as a child of the `<jnlp>` element.  The default is check="timeout" but maybe that's not sufficient for some reason.